# Expandable view of HTML Code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, expandablelistview

I am developing a editor where user can beautify and validate the HTML code and also convert the HTML Code to the expandable view where user can expand and collapse the HTML tags. I searched a lot on google but didn't find anything related to expandable view.

Is this possible through Javascript or Jquery?

Comment: what do you mean by expandable view here?

Comment: Do you mean like this: 
<p>this is an example</p>
would be collapsed to
<p>...</p>
or what exactly do you mean?

Comment: Like this- http://www.bodurov.com/JsonFormatter/ (This is for JSON)

Expandable tree view.

I want same for HTML Code

Comment: So basically the Chrome element inspector in devtools? This is of course possible in javascript (and therefore also possible in jQuery), and it's not too hard either. In short this could be accomplished by doing a mirror of the html code, and map each element in the mirrored tree to the real tree, then collapse <html> first. If the user presses <html>, set the contents of that to the real tree's content. And so on.

I do not know of such a lib that does this for you.

Comment: The answers posted here are pretty rotten so far.   If things don't get better, I'm going to close the question.

Comment: @PerMafrost Yes.. It is like Chrome element inspector in dev tools. Is there any existing plugin?

Answer (score -1):

May be [this plugin](https://github.com/mathiasbynens/jquery-details) can help you. [Here](https://mathiasbynens.be/demo/html5-details-jquery) is a demo.

If you don't care about compability, use simple html5 tag [details](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_details.asp).

UPD. May be I didn't undestand you correctly. I think you need tree plugins. Such [this](https://www.jstree.com/) or [this](http://www.jqueryrain.com/?X1gUmjkK).

Comment: No this is not what I want.

You can check this
bodurov.com/JsonFormatter (This is for JSON)

Comment: Yes, I'm sorry, You say that you want something like chrome web inspector. But, chrome web inspector is a tree. May be you need tree plugin?

Comment: Sort of.. Plugin which can structure HTML code as a tree view.